# Is it possible to shoot a chicken in a minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can shoot pigs, sheep and cows with a bow when they're in minecarts, but I'm having difficulty shooting chicken. Is it even possible? I can only hit the minecart.

Comment: Chickens are hard enough to hit when they're on flat ground, let alone when they've got a sweet ride to protect them.

Comment: @Zoredache: I think that he means that the chicken is the minecart, not him.

Comment: more importantly, why have you let a chicken be in charge of a complex railway system? they don't even have thumbs!

Comment: @Alex - in Minecraft, neither does the player. ;)

Comment: @Ullallulloo, ah, right.

Comment: It's nice to know I'm not the only one who does this sort of thing when they play video games.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've done some testing shooting a chicken in a minecart from directly above it, and I've had no luck hitting the chicken. It seems the hitbox of the minecart envelops the hitbox of the chicken. From my testing, the answer seems to be **no**, but I may be doing something wrong.

[image: Target practice!]

Answer (score 9):

I ran a few simple tests, and it looks like no, you can't.  The hitbox of the minecart completely swallows up the chicken, which becomes effectively invulnerable.  You just end up breaking the minecart.

Comment: what texture pack is that?

Comment: @Raven > It's my still all-time favourite, [Piehole](http://piehole.alexvoelk.de/)

Comment: Your video > my puny screenshot.

Comment: Does anyone know what's up with the vertical shaking in my video?  I used fraps.

Comment: @GnomeSlice are you using the half-size option? That may be causing it. Other than that, I dunno, it might be an artifact introduced by YouTube, I've never noticed anything like that with my own Frapsing

Comment: @Matthew > Not sure, it's only the free version, and this is the first time I've used it.

Comment: @GnomeSlice sorry, I havn't used it much before either, but I haven't seen anything like that before. I do know that Fraps uses it's own codec, so if you uploaded it straight to YT without reencoding it (which will make it a lot smaller too!), that may be causing issues too. If you play the video you uploaded locally, does it have the same issues? If not, then perhaps reencoding it before uploading will help fix it.

Comment: @Matthew > I did re-encode it.  You can tell that some of the edges are a bit cut off because I got my frame size wrong when I edited it. :P  No big deal.

Answer (score 7):

If you press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> you are able to see the hit boxes for all entities.

[image: Chicken in mine cart]

This shows that there is **no** way of hitting the chicken without destroying the mine cart first since the chicken's bounding box is way smaller then the mine cart its bounding box.