# Will animals spawn less likely in offline mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I usually play by myself in the single player game mode. Now I had to disable the internet access on my laptop because of an overload on internet usage. When playing Minecraft I searched for some pigs and horses to bring back to my city, but after an hour of looking around I only found a few chickens (that I happily murdered).

Do animals spawn less frequently in offline mode or is this just sheer coincidence?

Comment: @BillyMailman Although it's a subset of that question, it's not a dupe.

Comment: [What is it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21998/42984) [with people](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38554/42984) [murdering chickens](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/125834/42984)?

Comment: @Batphobia Dead chickens don't cluck.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, but dead cows don't moo.

Comment: Thats some insiteful comments XD just wanted to mention.. if you find yourself in an area with few mobs, don't kill them > breed them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Animal spawning is determined by your seed.

As a test, I used this seed: **-9057352651117540831** which is known to produce a lot of horses near spawn. I generated the world twice, offline and online. The results were the same, not just for the horses, but for all passive mobs.

Offline:
[image]

Online:
[image]

The groups of animals are generated in both instances.

Comment: Animal spawning stops being based on seed after level generation, though, doesn't it?

Comment: @BillyMailman In the situation in the question only level-gen spawning is really a factor.

Comment: I'll admit it's far more likely that the animals he ran into were from level-gen, but Minecraft does still have a small chance to spawn animals, right from tick one, so level-gen being identical doesn't automatically mean that spawns are the same.

Comment: @BillyMailman The spawnrate for passive mobs is negligible anyway. Any attempts to calculate it would be lost in the random number generator.

Comment: I notice a difference of 2 chickens between these images.

Comment: @Batophobia Animal groups are spawned, and the group size varies. It will always be at least one though (and I think there's another chicken out of frame)

Answer (score 11):

I'd put it down to pure coincidence. The spawning algorithm is based (primarily) on a random number generator, meaning that any result is guaranteed to be random. (Well, pseudo-random. I'll come back to this).

Some things to consider that may be affecting your chances:

- Animals do not spawn in desert or ocean biomes (except squid, but their spawning algorithm is different)
- Animal spawning is determined by the *world seed*, meaning that if you use the same seed, then the same chunks will contain the *same animals* (This is where the 'pseudo-randomness' comes from).
- Of newly generated chunks, 1/10 will contain mobs.
- Animals usually spawn in groups of 1-4 of the same animal
- They cannot spawn on transparent blocks.
- Initially, the block doesn't need to be grass, or illuminated
- When new animals spawn in already-generated chunks (which happens rarely), they need grass blocks with a light level of 9+.
- The grass/light requirement holds true for animals spawned using mob spawners.
- The only animals that can despawn are wild ocelots and *hostile* wolves.

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Animal_spawning)

Answer (score 9):

Animal spawning is guaranteed to be the same in both Survival Single Player and Survival Multiplayer. Mostly because "single player" mode is, and has been for a while, merely a local server running on your PC that only you can connect to.

Answer (score 8):

This is coincidence. The animal spawning algorithm has been analysed in fine detail and no part of it mentions accessing the internet at all. You can find information on the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Animal_spawning); animals are spawned in 1/10 of new chunks, but it's not evenly distributed, so sometimes you find a lot and sometimes very few.